# Azure Function Apps - Se in the admin portal how many instances that are running currently

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

Is there any way to see how man instances are running in a Function App in the admin portal? I tried looking in the live metrics but it just shows incomming requests and not the amount of running instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your function Monitoring, choose Process explorer, you will be able to check the running instance.

[image]

[image]

Also you could go to your kudu site, in the label if you have multiple instances, you will be able to list all instances.

[image]

Comment: That is just perfect! Thanks highly appreciated!

Comment: How do you do this if you have a Linux app? In that case, this button is greyed out.